# Splitting a polyline at vertices and calculating start and end measurements for new features based on a known measurement of the original polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, interpolation, splitting, measurements

I have a route network which has a length-attribute defining length of each feature. This length-attribute comes from a data register outside of gis.

Now I need to split each original feature at vertices and ad a start and end measure for each new feature. For example:

A polyline feature is 1000 meters long as a true coordinate based length but in the data register it's length is 1100 meters. Now this polyline consists of 5 lines which are 200, 250, 150, 300, 200 meters long. Now I need to split this polyline at vertices (forming 5 new features) and ad start-end measurement for each based new feature on the length of 1100 meters.

What tool should I use in ArcMap 10.3.1?

Comment: There is a tool in the Toolbox named "Split Line at Vertices" that could do it, though I believe you need an Advanced licence

Comment: If each line is M-aware and has already been populated from the external register, then you can use the tool mentioned by @FSimardGIS then use Field Calculator with the Python expression `!Shape.firstPoint.M!` and `!Shape.lastPoint.M!`.